# For loop that does different things to each file

Tags: bash

I am trying to make a for loop for JPG images to add them in html code with different properties for each image. I want to be able to change the content of the html code for each three images. Here is the current code:

```
for file in *.jpg
do
cat >> page.html << _EOF
<table class="super-centered"><tr><td style="width:100%;height:100%;" align="center" valign="middle" > <img alt="" src="${file}"> </td></tr></table>
<table class="super-centered"><tr><td style="width:100%;height:100%;" align="right" valign="right" > <img alt="" src="${file}"> </td></tr></table>
<table> class="super-centered"><tr><td style="width:100%;height:100%;" align="left" valign="left" > <img alt="" src="${file}"> </td></tr></table>
_EOF
done
```

I want the for loop to replace `${file}` in a way that the first image is centered, second image is right, and third image is left. Then the fourth image is centered, the 5th is right, and the 6th is left. And so on till all images are placed in the table.So basically change the content of cat for each 3 files in the loop. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a count and check the `case`:

```
i=0
for file in *.jpg
do
    case $i in
        0)
            cat << _EOF
    code one
  </div>
_EOF
            ;;
        1)
            cat << _EOF
    code two
  </div>
_EOF
            ;;
        2)
            cat << _EOF
    code three
  </div>
_EOF
            ;;
    esac
    ((i = (i+1) % 3))
done >> page.html
```

Note that `*.jpg` may not end up with the order you want.

Now that we know the desired output, we can generate it more easily:

```
#! /bin/bash
td_format='
    <td style="width:100%%;height:100%%;" align="%s" valign="%s" > <img alt="" src="%s"> </td>
'

set -- *.jpg

{
    echo '<table class="super-centered">'
    while [[ -n $1 ]]
    do
        echo '  <tr>'
        printf "$td_format" center middle "$1" right right "$2" left left "$3" 
        echo '  </tr>'
        shift 3
    done
    echo '</table>'
}> page.html
```

Here, the `td_format` variable is a format string for `printf`. `%s` in the format string is replaced by arguments to `printf` (and `%%` by `%`). `printf` loops over arguments, so we only need to specify one element's format here, and `printf` will take care of looping over the arguments to print enough lines.

Then, we set the script's arguments to the filenames. Now, we can access these filenames using `$1`, `$2`, etc. In the loop, then, I use `$1`, `$2` and `$3`, then remove these three using `shift 3`. Then the next three filenames become `$1`, `$2` and `$3` respectively. So, we can loop in batches of three.

Finally, instead of redirecting every command, I wrapped the whole block in `{ }` and redirected that group.

You probably should rethink the HTML and styling used here.

Comment: Thank you sir! This works like a charm! <3! 
Because I am learning may I ask another question? Do you think that is is possible to do the same in a for loop that is nested in a while loop? If yes, could you please demonstrate that? I am trying to do and would like to compare my code to that of an expert.. Thanks again! <3

Comment: @He-is-learning what exactly are you trying to do? I'd avoid nested loops and the code I've given in the answer isn't all that great. If you can describe the actual goal, it might be easier to do this

Comment: I just updated the question to show exactly what I am trying to do. Could you please also change your answer accordingly? Apologies that I didn't do so in the original question because I thought adding the html code might makes it look too messy. I will stick to your updated answer since you are the expert. However I wonder why would you avoid nested loops. Do they take more memory? Slower? More complicated or less elegant? Or a programmer hunch?

Comment: @He-is-learning slower, more complicated, less elegant. See update.